# Will adding a DC-DC converter affect how a modern car operates?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, automotive, wireless-charging

I'm thinking of adding a wireless charger to my car, and adding a Buck Converter to step down the 12V source to 5V for efficiency sake. However, I am worried about the emissions from the DC-DC converter effecting the vehicle. Is this something I should be concerned about? If so, what's an easy method to reducing the EMI emmisions from the Buck Converter?

Comment: Automobiles are already one of the most noisy electrical environments, with *huge* spikes from solenoids, pulsating DC from the alternator, usw, so your device should not add significant RFI. That said, it's good practice to put a ceramic capacitor across the input, and to keep the circuit away from the radio, due to possible radiation in the AM band.

Comment: There's no easy method to reduce the EMI. Circuit and PCB design, input and output filters, etc. are all used for EMI reasons. But also power levels are important. For example, I've seen a badly-designed 24V-to-12V 150W DC-DC converter working as an FM radio jammer in a coach. If your converter is something like 5V/1A then I don't think there'll be an EMI issue.

Comment: If the wireless charger is always connected to the cars battery, it will discharge it whenever the motor is not running. So if you fly away for holidays for a week or two, your car may not start.

Comment: All components used should be designed to be used in an automotive environment, hot temperatures and spikes of several 100 V on the 12 V DC.